# Database connection with Flex and C#/Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, apache-flex

I've started with Flex recently, I've noticed that some plugin for Visual Studio exist, instead of buying a licence for another program (Flex Builder).

I was wondering how I could manage to remotely connect to my database with a Flash/Flex application with the help of C#/Asp.Net.

If I've correctly understood what I've read in the last few days, there is basically no way to 'query' to a database with Flex 3. So I suppose there is another way by using a webservice in C# on the database server that would respond to the Http query from Flex.

Am I right or totally of the track? If you have any other thoughts about this, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should consider using FluorineFx.

It takes about 5 minutes to set up an will allow Flex to call your methods like a service. You can then pass classes back and forth from .NET to Flex and back.

It's also the standard form of communication by Adobe, it's free and it's super fast.

Comment: I have to agree. FlourineFX is a pretty good alternative to WebORB and works very much the same way as WebORB by having strongly typed objects on both ends.

Comment: Through FluorineFx you can also open up services that use the same models for a JSON feed.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer (and recommend) using Webservices for the communication between Flex and C#. It's easy to use, and they both support serialization, so you can easily transfer Strong-Typed Objects. More on Flex and .NET can be found at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_net.html

Alternatively, you could consider using WebORB. This program functions as a gateway between and Flex, and enables you to use the Flash RemoteObject API for the communication to C#. More on this can be found at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flextodotnet_remoteobject.html.

Comment: WebServices seems like an obvious choice, since its can also be used with other user interfaces.

Comment: FluorineFx can serve up JSON as well as AMF. When interacting with Flash AMF is the best way to go. Not much work to offer up a JSON feed as well as a Flash/AMF feed.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.  Flex is intended for developing client-side applications, and communication with a database is done through a server-side application.

Pretty much the same as building a JavaScript application.  Though, Flex has several additional options for communicating with the backend.  Webservices are great in a lot of cases, but the other options are worth looking into.

Here's a pretty happening article on the topic, if you haven't already seen it.

http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/33